# Structure for pagemodel selenium tests

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, pageobjects

I've recently dived into using selenium and page object models for testing i C# (coupled together with SpecFlow).

However, I am a bit uncertain about structure of the page object models in one of my cases.

As an example, I have a registration form, that spans multiple pages (fill out details, press next, fill out more details, press next, etc.)

Would it be best practice to create one page object model for each page in the flow, or to collect all into one page object model?

To spice things up, in some scenarios, the form elements might move to other pages in the flow (depending on end customer setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page objects is a well known design pattern, widely accepted by the automation engineers, to create separate class file for each page of the application to group all the elements as properties and their behaviors / business functionalities as methods of the class. But it might not be a great idea always, especially when the page has more / different sets of elements / complex element like a grid / calendar widget / a HTML table etc.

When you try to incorporate all the elements of a page in one single page class, it becomes too big to read, maintain etc. The class might contain too many responsibilities to handle. It can be restructured and broken into smaller classes.

I would expect my page objects to satisfy the **Single Responsibility Responsible**.

By doing so, you will end up with more classed for a page - but your tests will be so readable, reliable and robust.

You can see the examples here in Java. But I am sure You will get the idea.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/